# discord.py not connected to the voice

Tags: python, discord.py

i have beta bot and i got issue if bot is taking too long to search i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Luc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 1352, in invoke_command
  await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
File "C:\Users\Luc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\model.py", line 210, in invoke
  return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\Luc\Desktop\lucibot\main.py", line 102, in igraj
  song = await player.play()
File "C:\Users\Luc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\DiscordUtils\Music.py", line 197, in play
  self.voice.play(source, after=lambda error: self.after_func(self.ctx, self.ffmpeg_opts, self.music, self.after_func, self.on_play_func, self.loop))
File "C:\Users\Luc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 555, in play
  raise ClientException('Not connected to voice.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.
```

this is my code

```
@slash.slash()
@commands.cooldown(1,6,commands.BucketType.channel)
async def igraj(ctx, *, url):
    voicetrue = ctx.guild.me.voice
    
    if voicetrue is None:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
    if not player:
        player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=False)

    
    if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
        embed = discord.Embed(description='Iscem...', colour=0xf1c40f)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        sleep(1)
        await player.queue(url, search=True)
        song = await player.play()
        desc = f'Igram {song.name}'
        songe = discord.Embed(description = desc, colour=0xf1c40f)
        await msg.edit(embed=songe)

    else:
        song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
        embed=discord.Embed(description=f'{song.name} je v cakalni vrsti!', colour=0xf1c40f)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: you solved this? cause I have the same issue...